# Is Marshal padding?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have tried to reserve space for two arrays of 3 Int16 elements, a total of 6 bytes each array.
I need to declare each element explicitly within the structure.
At runtime, an error occurs due to misalignment.

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
  public struct Test
  {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 number;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string name;

    [FieldOffset(36)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public Byte[] array1;

    [FieldOffset(42)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public Int16[] array2;
  }
```

It is only solved if you move the offset from 42 to 44 for the second array.
Is there any possibility of eliminating padding? I have tried to fix it using 'Pack = 1' but without success.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: `At runtime, an error occurs due to misalignment.` Please show us that code.

Comment: You're helping too much.  [FieldOffset] has an affect for the managed layout as well.  Misaligning an array[] violates the .NET memory model, object reference updates must be atomic.  The GC relies on it.  Just don't use [FieldOffset] at all, it is not necessary since Pack=1 already gets the job done for the unmanaged layout.  With the additional benefit that the managed size is much smaller.

Comment: What processor option are you using (x86, 64 bit)?  The compiler aligns the data based on the microprocessor.  The properties within the struct are not padded but the start of the struct has is aligned.  Most likely you are corrupting the type bits that occur before the struct in memory.

Comment: Do you have an array of the structure Test?  Where is the array defined?  It is probably the array that is the issue.

Comment: Use Pack=4.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help.
Although all the answers are related, the reason why it doesn't work is the one explained by @Hans.
References must be atomic.
I have tried to put it in Sequential mode, using Pack = 4, = 2 and = 1 as (user)jdweng also says, and depending on how you order the fields, padding is created or not.
I will have to design the structure taking into account in which position to place the references.
Thank you!!

Comment: The Pack value is **not** arbitrary, be sure to ignore jdweng's comments.  You must pick a value that matches what the unmanaged compiler used.  Failure to do so causes a lot of trouble, memory corruption problems in particular become a lot harder to diagnose when you pinvoke.  We can't tell why you think 42 is the correct offset, it won't be when the unmanaged program is compiled with default settings, makes it hard to provide you with proper advice.